# Is the IdentityServer3 session configurable so it expires when the access token expires?

Tags: identityserver3

I need the IdentityServer3 session to expire at the same time as the access token.  When the access token expires the user is being redirected to IdSvr it's just automatically issuing new Id and Access tokens.  I want to force the user to authenticate again when the access token expires.  I'm using the Implicit flow so I don't believe refresh token lifetimes come into play.  I'm also using the OIDC-client-JS library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach doesn't make sense -- what would happen if there were 2 different access tokens?

The better approach is from the client to pass the prompt=login or max_age parameter on the authorization request. See the docs for more info: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/authorization.html

Comment: Excellent!  I've read the docs at least a dozen time but somehow I missed the prompt parameter.  IdentityServer rocks!